Where was the Umbrella Academy Timeline Subway tunnel footage filmed?
(I debated whether to post this here or on Movies & TV; if it’s too real-worldy for this stack, please feel free to migrate there instead.)

In season 4 of The Umbrella Academy, Five finds a subway that allows him (and Lila) to travel between alternate timelines. There are scenes in the subway station and on the trains, and a few times we see brief glimpses of the tunnel the train is going through, gradually developing Matrix-like colour effects to represent switching timelines. Here is a screenshot of the tunnels before the Technicolor sets in:

According to the Internet, the scenes in the subway station were filmed at the closed Bay Lower Station in Toronto (where most filming took place, it seems), and I presume the scenes inside the subway carriage were probably filmed in a studio; but I haven’t been able to find any indication of where the footage showing the tunnels themselves is taken from.
The reason I’m curious is that, being a resident of Copenhagen, this tunnel looks extremely familiar to me, being pretty much identical to the tunnels in the Copenhagen metro (which is driverless, so passengers look straight out into the tunnels). For comparison, here is a frame from this YouTube video of a metro journey that shows a similar stretch to the one above (except with the tunnel bending left instead of right):

Were these little tunnel glimpses filmed in Copenhagen (or perhaps just based on stock footage from the Copenhagen metro)? Or are there actually subway tunnels in Toronto that look so identical to the Copenhagen ones?

Economics suggests that it's likely that if some was known to be shot in Toronto then the rest probably was too.  Especially if it just involves having a camera looking out the front of the train and recording.  This video on YouTube shows that there are tunnels that look like that in Toronto too.  It's not proof (hence not an answer) but it is the most likely scenario.

@David Good find! I’d looked at some footage of Toronto tunnels, but only seen the square ones. The round tunnel in the last bit of that video looks a lot more like the Copenhagen ones.
